# Output vector of loop function r

Tags: r, loops, vector, resultset

i´m trying to create an output vector of a loop, containing a result from each loop.

```
out=NULL
for (i in 1:5)  {
out<-cbind(out,sample(1:100, 1))  #placeholderfunction
for (i in 1:5) {out[i]<- i+1}  
}
```

The good side: My result contains the correct values. The bad side: it does as a matrix and i don´t know why.

```
> out
     out            
[1,]   2 71 14 46 96
[2,]   3 71 14 46 96
[3,]   4 71 14 46 96
[4,]   5 71 14 46 96
[5,]   6 71 14 46 96
```

What i want would be  something like:

```
> out
     out            
[1,]   2 71 14 46 96
```

Probably it is just a small step from where i stand, but i just can´t figure it out, maybe someone could help?
(and yes i could just remove but i would like my code clean)

Thanks!

Ok,
by looking at the problem again on this scale i found it - a superfluous line:

```
> out=NULL
> for (i in 1:5)  {
+ out<-cbind(out,sample(1:100, 1))
+ }
> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   63   98   78   43   19
```

Comment: growing a vector in a loop is bad practice (as are loops in r in general). Why not do `out <- numeric(5)` then `out[i] <- sample(1:100, 1)` inside the loop. Or, `out <- sample(1:100, 5, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for your advice on the loops, though i got the Problem that what i called a function here (for reasons of simplicity) is in fact a simulation of multiple randomized datasets to specify the accuracy of an algorithm (and i´m still a beginner). I´ll have a read here on loops in R, thanks for mentioning!

Comment: In the way that you're using this (as a vector, not a matrix), you should use `c()` instead of `cbind()`. **However**, listen to jeremycg's advice about "growing" an object - it destroys performance and can make even simple code take a long time.

Answer (score -1):

What about this

```
 out <- sample(100,5)
```

**Update**

I see why I got a -1, the OP wants to construct a vector with a for loop.  As a word of caution, creating a vector in this manner is usually not a good idea.  For example, my above code is both simpler and faster than the OP's code.  That withstanding, if you want generate a vector of random numbers with a for loop use this approach

```
my.loop <- function(l){
    out_1 <- numeric(l)
    for (i in 1:l)  {
        out_1[i] <- sample(1:100, 1)
    }
    out_1
}
```

This will be much better than op approach below because we are preallocating memory.

```
op.loop <- function(l){
    out_2 = NULL
    for (i in 1:l)  {
        out_2 <- cbind(out_2, sample(1:100, 1))
    }
    out_2
}
```

For fun I timed the two approaches:

[image]